# opencv cv2.imshow automatically add padding to small image

Tags: python, opencv, imshow

I try to use cv2.imshow() to display images, however I find that the result is padded with blank automatically. The code I use is as following:

```
import cv2
if __name__ == '__main__':   
    img = cv2.imread('test2.png')
    cv2.imshow('dafasf', img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if key == 27: # ESC
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: the image I used]  [image]

Comment: Can you try with a bigger image? Maybe it has a minimum window size and your image is smaller than that?

Comment: You are right, there is no problem when I try a bigger image. Maybe there is a minimum window size in OpenCV. And we can use cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL tag to manually control the window size according to the following answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `imshow` creates window object with `WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` attribute. It means that window size is determined by some frontend (GUI) which **OpenCV** was compiled with.

Your image are not actually changed, it is just displaying issue.

If you want to manually control window attributes, you can try to create `namedWindow` with your attributes before `imshow` call, i. e. something like this:

```
cv2.namedWindow("window name", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("window name", img)
```

According to [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html) there are 3 attributes for window displaying (`WINDOW_NORMAL`, `WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` and `WINDOW_OPENGL`), but with the following simple snippet you can determine your actually supported values (in my version I see `WINDOW_FREERATIO`, `WINDOW_FULLSCREEN`, `WINDOW_AUTOSIZE`, `WINDOW_NORMAL`, `WINDOW_KEEPRATIO` and `WINDOW_OPENGL`):

`[i for i in list(cv2.__dict__.keys()) if i[:6] == 'WINDOW']`